# drupal_add_js in input filter

Tags: javascript, input-formats

I have a module that provides an input filter for Drupal 6 and 7. It renders some elements using a (heavy) JavaScript module that I don't want to include on every page.

In Drupal 6 the input filter would run and if a element that needed rendering was present the JavaScript files were added using the `drupal_add_js(...)` method in the process step of the input filter. This works fine.

In Drupal 7 however, `drupal_add_js(...)` is only executed when I clear the cache. Otherwise the page is rendered but the JavaScript files aren't added. At first I thought that this was due to caching of the input filter. However I have set `cache=>FALSE` for `hook_filter_info()` and indeed `$cache` is `FALSE` in the process step.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Where is your drupal_add_js() call located? If its inside of hook_filter_info() it will not work as expected. A better option is to use form alter and attach the JS.

Comment: It's inside the process callback that is provided by `hook_filter_info`.